# Fullcalendar is putting my events into the "all-day" category

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I'm doing some stuff with fullcalendar and views that, more or less, is working.  In particular, a month view properly shows a set of events on the day in which they're scheduled. However, when I switch to week or day view, the events show up in the "all day" part of the calendar.

The nodes' fields containing the dates definitely correspond to specific times. How can I get them properly showing up in the right time areas in those calendar views?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed; my bad.  I hadn't (properly) set the granularity of the node's time field.  Duh.